# How can I change my chef node FQDN?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I created a chef node, then changed its name following this [guide](https://docwhat.org/rename-chef-node/). But now my FQDN is still set to the original name.  I am using the [hostname](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/hostname) cookbook, but if I try setting the `node['set_fqdn']` attribute on the node it doesn't update the hostname?  how am I able to update my hostname / fqdn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [chef_hostname](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef_hostname) cookbook instead.  It is significantly more portable, supports setting FQDNs as hostnames and does the correct magic to run at `compile_time` so that the hostname is set and ohai attributes are reloaded early.